# java - error: cannot find symbol . in generated classes SomeDirections.SomeAction

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-bundle, android-safe-args

I am implementing navigation between Fragments from different flows (single-activity architecture with flow fragments) meaning from one nested graph to another. I am trying to pass one `testID` argument using *Safe Args*. In my origins Fragment I use generated class to create action to further set parameter:

```
LevelFlowFragmentDirections.ActionGlobalTestFlowFragment action = LevelFlowFragmentDirections.actionGlobalTestFlowFragment();
action.setTestID(1);
```

However, when I run the project it shows this error:

[image: error: cannot find symbol]

Here is what my project structure looks like:

[image: project structure]

LevelFlowFragment.java code:

```
package kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.levelflow;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.NavDirections;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import kz.rating.onaikazakh.NavGraphDirections;
import kz.rating.onaikazakh.R;
import kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.recyclerviews.section.SectionAdapter;
import kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.utils.NavUtils;

public class LevelFlowFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


    private NavController navController;
    LevelsViewModel vm;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*vm = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(LevelsViewModel.class);
        vm.data.observe(this, data -> {
            if (data!=null) adapter = new SectionAdapter(this, data);
        });*/
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flow_fragment_level, container, false);

        RecyclerView levelsRecView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_test_list);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        levelsRecView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        int scrollposition = ((LinearLayoutManager) levelsRecView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        levelsRecView.scrollToPosition(scrollposition);
        SectionAdapter adapter = new SectionAdapter(this, new String[]{"level 1", "level 2", "level 3"});
        levelsRecView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);

        Button button_skip = getView().findViewById(R.id.button_test_skip);
        button_skip.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        NavUtils.navigate(R.id.action_global_mainFlowFragment, this);
    }

    public void onViewHolderClickListener(String level){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        LevelFlowFragmentDirections.ActionGlobalTestFlowFragment action = LevelFlowFragmentDirections.actionGlobalTestFlowFragment();
        NavDirections directions = LevelFlowFragmentDirections.actionGlobalTestFlowFragment();
//temporary implementation
        switch(level){
            case "level 1":
                action.setTestID(1);
                bundle.putInt("testID", 1);
                break;
            case "level 2":
                action.setTestID(2);
                bundle.putInt("testID", 2);
                break;
            case "level 3":
                action.setTestID(3);
                bundle.putInt("testID", 3);
                break;
        }
        NavUtils.navigate(R.id.action_global_testFlowFragment, this, bundle);

    }


}
```

Main graph nav_graph.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    tools:ignore="InvalidNavigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/langFlowFragment">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_signFlowFragment"
        app:destination="@id/signFlowFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_mainFlowFragment"
        app:destination="@id/mainFlowFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_levelFlowFragment"
        app:destination="@id/levelFlowFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_langFlowFragment"
        app:destination="@id/langFlowFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_testFlowFragment"
        app:destination="@id/testFlowFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph">
        <argument
            android:name="testID"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="0" />
    </action>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFlowFragment"
        android:name="kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.mainflow.MainFlowFragment"
        android:label="flow_fragment_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/flow_fragment_main" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/signFlowFragment"
        android:name="kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.signflow.SignFlowFragment"
        android:label="flow_fragment_sign"
        tools:layout="@layout/flow_fragment_sign" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/levelFlowFragment"
        android:name="kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.levelflow.LevelFlowFragment"
        android:label="flow_fragment_level"
        tools:layout="@layout/flow_fragment_level" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/langFlowFragment"
        android:name="kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.langflow.LanguageFlowFragment"
        android:label="flow_fragment_lang"
        tools:layout="@layout/flow_fragment_lang" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/testFlowFragment"
        android:name="kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.testflow.TestFlowFragment"
        android:label="flow_fragment_test"
        tools:layout="@layout/flow_fragment_test" >
        <argument
            android:name="testID"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="0" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

test_graph.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/test_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/questionFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/questionFragment"
        android:name="kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.testflow.question.QuestionFragment"
        android:label="fragment_question"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test_question">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_questionFragment_to_answerFragment"
            app:destination="@id/answerFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="testID"
            app:argType="integer"
            android:defaultValue="0" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/answerFragment"
        android:name="kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.testflow.answer.AnswerFragment"
        android:label="fragment_answer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test_answer">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_answerFragment_to_questionFragment"
            app:destination="@id/questionFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_answerFragment_to_completedFragment"
            app:destination="@id/completedFragment" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/completedFragment"
        android:name="kz.rating.onaikazakh.presentation.ui.fragments.testflow.completion.CompletionFragment"
        android:label="fragment_completed"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_test_complete">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_completedFragment_to_questionFragment"
            app:destination="@id/questionFragment" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

flow_fragment_test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wave_imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/wave" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_test"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_top_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_bottom_margin">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_test"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/test_graph" />

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

build.gradle :app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kz.rating.onaikazakh"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/navigation-args'
            }
        }
    }


}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    def nav_version = "2.5.3"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // Feature module Support
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"

    // Jetpack Compose Integration
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"


    implementation project(path: ':domain')
    implementation project(path: ':data')
}
```

build.gradle :project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'

        def nav_version = "2.5.3"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**What I have tried:**

1. Clean, Rebuild
2. I saw [Safeargs library doesnt generate direction class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686907/safeargs-library-doesnt-generate-direction-class), and added

```
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/navigation-args'
            }
        }
    }
```

3. Updated all dependencies and plugins
4. I also saw [Build error: Cannot find symbol. Points to navigation actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70130997/build-error-cannot-find-symbol-points-to-navigation-actions), but the author deleted nested graph which worked. In my case I cannot apply this solution.
5. Saw [Action is not generated in FragmentDirections when Fragment is used in a second nav graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655775/action-is-not-generated-in-fragmentdirections-when-fragment-is-used-in-a-second), but I already have @+id in the action and in every graph.

*6) Off-topic: later I tried another way of passing data via creating Bundle and retrieving it in both `QuestionFragment` and `TestFlowFragment`. Neither it produced errors nor passed any data. This is code from destination fragment*

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        vm = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(TestSharedViewModel.class);
        int id = getArguments().getInt("testID");
        Log.v("AAA", "id is " + id);
        vm.setID(id);

    }
```

I would appreciate any help on resolving the problem or other ways to implement passing data between those fragments.

**Edit**
[What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)
Does not resolve my issue. Most of them are about wrong import, dependencies or misspelling, but these are generated classes, `LevelFlowFragmentDirections.ActionGlobalTestFlowFragment` was offered by IDE; when I tried to remove the `LevelFlowFragmentDirections` to follow official android guide it offered referencing `LevelFlowFragmentDirections.ActionGlobalTestFlowFragment` from different modules(?) and I tried both app and app.main.
In regard to JDK and Gradle compatability, it used to be 1.8 with gradle 4.0.1, I upgraded to 11 and 7.0.2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I worked it out. For some reason IDE suggested `LevelFlowFragmentDirections.ActionGlobalTestFlowFragment`, whereas when I looked into the **app->build->generated->source** the no inner class `ActionGlobalTestFlowFragment` in `LevelFlowFragmentDirections`. Instead, there was `NavGraphDirections` with `ActionGlobalTestFlowFragment` in it.

*The post suggested by @Jens did contain the answer, IDE highlights can be extremely misleading though.*